# OpenGL - pausing an animation with a keystroke

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to pause the entire animation indefinitely until the user presses the same key again. I have a crude pause using usleep:

```
#include <unistd.h>

...

if(key == 'p')
    usleep(200000);
```

Ideally though, I want the time to be indefinite until p is pressed again (and usleep measures in milliseconds so it's not very useful) Can someone point me in the direction of how to do this?

Comment: Ideally you can just stop calling whatever part of your main loop advanced the animation. Can you give us an idea of how your main loop is structured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static bool paused = false;
if(key == 'p')
  paused = !paused;

// Somewhere in your main loop.
if(!paused)
  Render();
```

You'll also probably want to try checking for key *up* and not key down, otherwise you'll pause and resume very rapidly.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be what I'm looking for. What is Render() though? I tried adding that conditional to my main loop but I'm guessing Render is not part of openGL?

Comment: It's just an example function. Try and encompass all your rendering logic in a high level function like `Render()`. That way, if you want to stop rendering, you just don't call the function. No, it's not part of openGL.

Comment: @user1799323 Also the animation is probably triggered by setting some variable to a certain value. This also makes it possible to interrupt completely the currently running animation and starting a new one. Depending on the work put into it each animated state should have some sort of an "interruption" transition. For example if a character walks left and you suddenly make it stop in order to keep the immersion a smooth transition between the walking and the stopping has to be done (the transition itself is an animation also).